# How to print own class with jsonify in flask?

Tags: python, json, class, flask

I create class:

```
class My_class:
    def __init__(self, List):
        self.lst = List

    def __str__(self):
        return '[' + ', '.join(str(e) for e in self.lst) + ']'
```

But it doesn't work when I try to print jsonify with My_class
This code doesn't work:

```
from flask import jsonify

def Print():
   return jsonify({"list": My_class([6, 9])})
```

I need to print My_class without **""**

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Surround `My_class([6, 9])` with `str()` as the class itself isn't JSON serializable.

```py
import json

def Print():
    return flask.jsonify({"list": json.loads(str(My_class([6, 9])))})
```

Comment: It print `"list": "My_class"`, but I wrote that I need print without **"** (`"list": My_class`)

Comment: Now it  print in many rows  `[; 6,; 9; ]`, but i need print in one row (I create this class for it)